# launchctl won't load php-fpm with this LaunchAgent

Tags: mac-osx, logging, php-fpm, launchd, launchctl

I'm trying to start `php-fpm` with `launchctl`.

Running directly from the command line is no problem:

```
$ /usr/sbin/php-fpm -p /Users/dmitry -e
```

Here's the contents of `/Users/dmitry/Library/LaunchAgents/dminkovsky.php-fpm.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>dminkovsky.php-fpm</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/sbin/php-fpm</string>
      <string>-p</string>
      <string>/Users/dmitry/var</string>
      <string>-e</string>
    </array>
    <key>EnableGlobbing</key>
    <true/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

For some reason the process doesn't start with this `.plist`. Nothing is logged, either, so I don't know why. In `/var/log/system.log`, I have:

```
Nov 18 08:38:30 airosol com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[285] (dminkovsky.php-fpm[19833]): Exited with code: 78
Nov 18 08:38:30 airosol com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[285] (dminkovsky.php-fpm): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

I don't know where to take it from here though.

- Googled around for the meaning of exit code `78`. Found out it's in a non-reserved range of exit codes.
- I don't know what to do with the contents of `/var/log/com.apple.launchd.peruser.503`.
- Tried to get some more logging with advice from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677493/php-fpm-doesnt-write-to-error-log, but that didn't work.

Most oddly, this `.plist` used to work before upgrading to Mavericks.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

php-fpm's error code 78 seems to correspond to EX_CONFIG (see one of the messages [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62033&edit=1)), indicating some sort of configuration error. It's possible the error is preventing php-fpm from using any of your configured settings, including logging settings. You may be able to get more information by capturing the stdin and stdout from the php-fpm process by adding something like this to your .plist:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/php-fhm-out.log</string>
<key> StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/log/php-fhm-err.log</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately neither output redirect yielded results written to file upon attempting to load/start.